# Display progress in a single progress bar for downloading multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm, file, cordova

I am building an ionic app for Android platform. I am using cordova's FileTransfer plugin to download files. I am able to download multiple files but not able to display single progress bar for all concurrent downloads.

What is the proper way of displaying progress for multiple files in a single progress bar? Below is my function code for reference:

> Function to download multiple files by calling a single file download function in loop

```
$scope.downloadSongs = function () {
            angular.forEach($scope.album, function (song) {
                if (song.checked) {
                    $scope.downloadSong(song);
                }
            });
        };
```

> Function to download a file

```
$scope.downloadSong = function (song) {
                $scope.downloads = $scope.downloads + 1;
                console.log("Downloads - " + $scope.downloads);
                var url = decodeURI(song.link);
                console.log(url);
                var filename = song.name + ".mp3";
                var folder = song.folder;
                var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "musicbox/" + folder + "/" + filename;
                $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath)
                    .then(function (entry) {
                        cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                            title: "Download Complete",
                            message: song.name
                        });
                    }, function (error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    }, function (progress) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                        })
                    });
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass the song id in the view

```
<li ng-repeat="song in songsList">
<progress id="{{song.id}}" max="100" value=""></progress>
</li>
```

Than in the controller

```
function(progress){
document.getElementById(song.id).value(Math.ceil((progress.loaded/progress.total)*100));
}
```